# Cannot start artisan serve in laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am using laravel 5, when I try to start server from

```
php artisan serve
```

I get following error :

> [Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException] 
>   App\Providers\RouteServiceProvider::App\Providers{closure}(): Failed
>   opening required 'D:\Test\app\app\Http/routes.php'
>   (include_path='.;C:\xampp\php\pear')

I tried `composer dump-autoload`, it was successfull, but when i do

```
composer update
```

I get the same error.

How to resolve it?

Comment: First check your routes.php file exist under app/Http/ directory if exist check file permission and which php version you have.

Answer (score -1):

`routes.php` was never in `app\Http`, it was in someother dir. Moving it back where it belongs fixed the issue

Comment: I have no idea how mine disappeared but thank you so much for that!

Comment: @Gautam Kumar It was in the past located in `app\Http`! Have a look at github repo in version 5.2: https://github.com/laravel/laravel/tree/5.2/app/Http